# Python Playwright - How can I check that an element does not have an href?

Tags: python, playwright-python

As part of my automated testing I'm trying to validate that an href is correctly removed from an element on the page.

```py
from playwright.sync_api import Page, expect

def test_reset_button(page: Page):
    page.goto("https://www.example.com")
    page.locator("#reset").click()
    expect(page.locator("#download")).not_to_have_attribute("href", value="")
```

In my example code above it ends up testing that the href attribute on the element is not equal to `value=""`, which means that if `value="nonsense"` this test will pass.

Based on the [`not_to_have_attribute`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-not-to-have-attribute) documentation it seems that you have to pass a value to it to test that it does not have that specific value. I'd like to test that the "href" attribute does not exist on the element at all.

How can I test for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex `.|` to test attribute presence, including both `href="something"` and `href=""`. The `""` case is handled by the empty string on the right of the alternation pipe. You could read the pattern as "match either something or nothing" (i.e. all possible strings).

```py
import re
from playwright.sync_api import expect, Page, sync_playwright  # 1.37.0


sample_html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<button id="reset">reset</button>
<a id="download" href="nonsense">download</a>
<script>
document.querySelector("#reset").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector("#download").removeAttribute("href");
});
</script>"""


def test_reset_button(page: Page):
    page.set_content(sample_html)
    dl = page.locator("#download")

    # assert that there is an href present initially
    expect(dl).to_have_attribute("href", re.compile(r".|"))

    # trigger an event to remove the href
    page.locator("#reset").click()

    # assert that there is no longer an href present after the click
    expect(dl).not_to_have_attribute("href", re.compile(r".|"))



def main():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch()
        test_reset_button(browser.new_page())
        browser.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`re.compile` is important. Using `".|"` or `"/.|/"` would treat it as a literal string to test equality against.

Another approach is to query the element, store the exact href in a variable, click the button to remove the href, then assert that the exact href you saved before is no longer present. This would give a false positive if the href changed to something else, but it seems worth mentioning since it may be useful in certain cases.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work when `href=""` because `re.compile('.')` will fail.

Comment: So the initial attribute is `href=""`, which is then removed? Please see the update, which should work on either `href=""` or `href="anything else"`. If that doesn't work, please show a simple HTML snippet like I've done, except one that matches your use case so we're on the same page.

Comment: Your updated regex works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions come to the rescue. The value parameter can be a Pattern, that is a [regular expression](https://github.com/aparrish/rwet/blob/master/regular-expressions-a-gentle-introduction.ipynb) `.*` (which stand any sequence of characters, i.e anything) or, if you prefer, `.?` (arbitrary symbol or nothing) will catch both "nonsense" and the empty value.

While, in my opinion playwright devs should keep value as an optional parameter, I suggest you master the art of regular expressions,  they are a powerful tool to express fine requirements which are difficult to catch otherwise. In the [playwright intro](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) they give example of using a regex to simply test a presence of a substring in a page title, but you can do much more with it.

Note, sometimes regular expression might could be tricky and need a bit of debugging. Note ggorlen was not able to arrive to correct expression immediately. To debug complex expression we use dedicated debuggers [online](https://www.debuggex.com/) or within IDE. More  confusingly, regular expression are implemented slightly differently in different languages, but that's mainly concerns the advance features.

Comment: Unfortunately this passes for elements that have hrefs.

Comment: They both pass. I'm trying to test that there is no href attribute at all.

Comment: No, both fail. Yet, as ggorlen, explained in his answer, with playwright the regular expression should be compiled.